# How draw a perpendicular line in a face

Tags: opencv, line

I need to draw a perpendicular line given a line... I'm programming in C++ using OpenCV, I would want the source code in this language, thanks.

Comment: adding to @Haris answer http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line kindly have a look.

Answer (score 0):

If your given lines co-ordinates is something like

```
 Point pt1(x1,y1);
 Point pt2(x2,y2);
 line(src, pt1, pt2, Scalar(255,255,255),1,8,0);
```

You can draw a perpendicular line to it like

```
 //Draw perpendicular line to middle of given line
 Point pt3(x2-x1,0);
 Point pt4(x2-x1,y2);
 line(src, pt3, pt4, Scalar(255,255,255),1,8,0);
```

Comment: Well, I want this perpendicular line in a face detected with viola-jones using OpenCV 2.1... this is my result and the perpendicular line has to cross the entire face

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62123408/face_eyes_violajones.avi